# Start applescript from USB?

Tags: linux, macos, operating-system, usb, applescript

i have an applescript on my USB.
I want to run some shell commands and/or an applescript from my USB automatically.
Is this possible?

Example:
1. Insert the USB to MAC
2. Automatically run some shell commands or an applescript (Which are on my USB)

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Yes, it's possible with `launchd`

Answer (score 0):

By itself, NO. Apple Computers do not have a built-in function that autoruns USB's like Windows, (Windows autoruns USBs with "autorun.inf" inside). But you could make your own software (eg. Launch Daemon/Agent) that will run a background script waiting for a USB to be inserted with a custom file, etc... and run it